# how to make this function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I run this, I get error getInfo is not defined. So how do I accomplish this, then?

(I know this isn't a secure login, I'm not worrying about that right now)

```
 document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function getInfo(){
                    var user = document.getElementById('username');
                    var username = user.value;
                    var pass = document.getElementById('password');
                    var password = pass.value;
                    return [username, password];
            });

            var userinfo = getInfo();
            var username = userinfo[0];
            var password = userinfo[1];

            console.log(username, password);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
function getInfo(){
    var user = document.getElementById('username');
    var username = user.value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('password');
    var password = pass.value;
    return [username, password];
 });

 document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function (){ getInfo();});
 //or
 //document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", getInfo);

 var userinfo = getInfo();
 var username = userinfo[0];
 var password = userinfo[1];

 console.log(username, password);
```

Comment: Or `document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", getInfo, false);`